# Finding the number of orders between two dates based on customer id

Tags: sql, presto

I have the dataset where I need to find the count of orders between two dates based on customer id. For example the following tables. I want to join the tables and find the count of orders from Table B that happened between the last date shown for customer_id 13 and the previous date available for customer_id 13 in Table A. So, in this case between `2022-11-21 06:22:08` and `2022-11-17 05:36:19`   which is 3 for customer id 13.

Table A

| created | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-15 16:44:30 | 13 |
| 2022-11-17 5:36:19 | 13 |
| 2022-11-21 6:22:08 | 13 |
| 2022-11-11 12:53:32 | 14 |
| 2022-11-19 13:52:45 | 14 |
| 2022-11-20 14:12:07 | 14 |

Table B

| order_created | order_id | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-15 18:13:35 | 1234 | 13 |
| 2022-11-17 6:46:11 | 4567 | 13 |
| 2022-11-17 10:35:23 | 5678 | 13 |
| 2022-11-17 19:52:15 | 9876 | 13 |
| 2022-11-21 2:02:07 | 9809 | 13 |
| 2022-11-20 12:12:08 | 7777 | 14 |
| 2022-11-19 18:59:17 | 3234 | 14 |

Basically, I am having trouble finding orders between two dates when I need to group them by customer id.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

1. calculate date ranges by `customer_id` in `table_a`
2. join to `table_b` to get orders placed between ranges `from_ts`, `to_ts`
3. aggregate to `customer_id` and date ranges to get order count

```
with cte_range as (
select customer_id,
       created  as from_ts,
       lead(created,1) over (partition by customer_id order by created)  as to_ts
  from table_a)
select b.customer_id,
       r.from_ts,
       r.to_ts,
       count(*) as order_count
  from table_b b
  join cte_range r
 using (customer_id)
 where b.order_created between r.from_ts and r.to_ts
group by 1,2,3
order by 1,2;
```

Output:

```
customer_id|from_ts                |to_ts                  |order_count|
-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
         13|2022-11-15 16:44:30.000|2022-11-17 05:36:19.000|          1|
         13|2022-11-17 05:36:19.000|2022-11-21 06:22:08.000|          4|
         14|2022-11-19 13:52:45.000|2022-11-20 14:12:07.000|          2|
```